# Como fazer um objeto dentro de um objeto JSON em Java?

Tags: java, json

Estou tentando montar o seguinte JSON:

```
{
   "movies":
        {
        "filme":
            [
            {
                "id":1,
                "titulo":"Os Arquivos JSON ",
            },
            {
                "id":2,
                "titulo":"Sexta-feira 13: JSON vive",
            }
            ]
        }
}
```

Estou usando a biblíoteca `org.json`. Como eu posso fazer para adicionar novos elementos a esse meu array filme? Por exemplo:

```
{
    "id":3,
    "id":"Tubarão",
}
```

Código:

```
package webNavegator;


import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Controller {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String str;
            str = "{\"movies\":{\"filme\":[{\"id\":1,\"titulo\":\"Os Arquivos JSON \"},{\"id\":2,\"titulo\":\"Sexta-feira 13: JSON vive\"}]}}";;
            JSONObject movies = new JSONObject(str);  
        }

}
```

Comment: sem mostrar seu código fica dificil ajudar

Comment: ok, já vou atualizar o post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não ficou muito claro o que você quer fazer.

Se quer criar um `JSONObject` com os 3 filmes, adicione o terceiro filme na `String` que você já tem:

```
str = "{\"movies\":{\"filme\":[{\"id\":1,\"titulo\":\"Os Arquivos JSON \"},{\"id\":2,\"titulo\":\"Sexta-feira 13: JSON vive\"},{\"id\":3,\"titulo\":\"Tubarão\"}]}}";
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
```

---

Agora se você já tem um `JSONObject` criado, e quer manipulá-lo para adicionar o terceiro filme, a solução é diferente. Mas antes você precisa entender [a estrutura e sintaxe de um JSON](http://json.org/), pois isso facilita na hora de lê-lo e manipulá-lo:

- O que você tem é um objeto, pois está delimitado por `{ }`.

  - Este objeto possui a chave `"movies"`, cujo valor é outro objeto.

    - Este outro objeto possui a chave `"filme"`, cujo valor é um array (pois está delimitado por `[ ]`)

      - Cada elemento deste array é um objeto, contendo as chaves `"id"` e `"titulo"`
      - Os elementos do array são separados por vírgula

Segue abaixo o JSON com explicações sobre a sua estrutura:

```js
{  <-- início do objeto
   "movies":  <- chave "movies"
        {  <- valor da chave "movies", é outro objeto
        "filme":  <- chave "filme"
            [  <- valor da chave "filme", é um array
              {  <- primeiro elemento do array, é um objeto
                "id":1,  <- chave "id", valor 1
                "titulo":"Os Arquivos JSON ",  <- chave "titulo" e valor "Os Arquivos JSON "
              },  <- essa vírgula separa os elementos do array
              {  <- segundo elemento do array, é um objeto
                "id":2,  <- chave "id", valor 1
                "titulo":"Sexta-feira 13: JSON vive",  <- chave "titulo" e valor "Sexta-feira 13: JSON vive"
              }
            ]  <- fecha o array
        }  <- fecha o objeto referente à chave "movies"
}  <-- fim do objeto
```

Então se você quer adicionar um novo filme no array, basta fazer o seguinte:

- criar o objeto que corresponde ao novo filme (com `"id"` igual a 3 e `"titulo"` igual a "Tubarão")
- adicionar este objeto no array (que está na chave `"filme"` do objeto que, por sua vez, está na chave `"movies"`)

Algo assim:

```
String str = "{\"movies\":{\"filme\":[{\"id\":1,\"titulo\":\"Os Arquivos JSON \"},{\"id\":2,\"titulo\":\"Sexta-feira 13: JSON vive\"}]}}";
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str); // JSONObject original, só com 2 filmes

// cria o objeto do novo filme
JSONObject novoFilme = new JSONObject();
novoFilme.put("id", 3);
novoFilme.put("titulo", "Tubarão");

obj
    // pega a chave "movies", que é outro objeto
    .getJSONObject("movies")
    // pega a chave "filme", que é um array
    .getJSONArray("filme")
    // adiciona o novo filme no array
    .put(novoFilme);
```

Você também poderia ter feito assim para criar o novo filme:

```
JSONObject novoFilme = new JSONObject("{\"id\":3,\"titulo\":\"Tubarão\"}");
```

Mas se o objeto a ser criado for muito grande e complexo, talvez seja melhor adicionar as chaves uma a uma, deixando o código mais claro e menos propenso a erros de digitação, já que é muito fácil se perder no meio de vários pares de `{}` e `[]` quando um objeto fica muito grande.

Repare também que não chamei o objeto principal de `movies`. Afinal, ele não **é** um objeto `movies`, ele **tem** uma chave `"movies"`. Eu só dei um nome meio genérico (`obj`) porque não tenho todo o contexto (afinal, ele poderia ter outras chaves com informações diferentes), senão daria um nome melhor.

---

Por fim, algo que não está diretamente relacionado: a estrutura deste JSON está meio esquisita.

Por que ter uma chave `"movies"`, e depois uma chave `"filme"`, que por fim leva ao array de filmes? Isso me parece bem redundante (sem contar que `"filme"` [deveria estar no plural](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad), já que seu valor é uma lista de vários filmes), poderia ser apenas assim:

```js
{
   "movies":
      [
        {
          "id":1,
          "titulo":"Os Arquivos JSON ",
        },
        {
          "id":2,
          "titulo":"Sexta-feira 13: JSON vive",
        }
      ]
}
```

Apenas uma chave `"movies"`, cujo valor é o array de filmes (ou mude o nome da chave para `"filmes"`, sei lá).

Claro que depende muito do contexto, mas a princípio não parece haver necessidade de se criar um nível a mais na estrutura, pois não há nenhum ganho aparente em fazê-lo (você só complicou o JSON à toa).

Na verdade, se você só quer uma lista de filmes, talvez nem precise ser um objeto. Poderia ser simplesmente um array:

```js
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "titulo":"Os Arquivos JSON ",
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "titulo":"Sexta-feira 13: JSON vive",
  }
]
```

Neste caso, você manipularia este JSON diretamente como um `JSONArray`.

Novamente, estou dando estas sugestões sem ter todo o contexto. Se for uma estrutura mais complexa e a lista de filmes é apenas uma das informações retornadas, aí faz sentido ter um objeto (ainda sim, não parece fazer muito sentido ter a chave `"filme"` dentro de `"movies"`).

Answer (score 2):

Sei que a questão em si já foi respondida, porém, algo interessante é não tentar reinventar a roda, ou seja, utilizar métodos, libs e afins para realizar a operação que se deseja sem a necessidade de passar todo um esforço novamente..
A biblioteca Gson da Google ajuda muito no quesito, sendo muito facil de usar..
Para transformar uma classe em formato Json basta declarar:

```java
Filme meuFilme = new Filme("nao sei os parametros");
String json = new Gson().toJson(meuFilme); //basta que sua classe Filme implemente Serializable
```

e para obter sua classe novamente basta:

```java
Filme filme = new Gson().fromJson(json, Filme.class); //json seria seu filme em formato string Json
```

para arrays basta:

```java
Filme[] filmes = new Gson().fromJson(json,Filme[].class);
```